# Symfony - Specifying a service as not shared using annotations

Tags: php, symfony

How do we specify a service as not a shared service using annotations?
Is it possible?

Comment: I know you are coming from a java spring background where di annotations are common.  Symfony, uses yaml or xml files out of the box.  It takes an add on to even do the basic annotations and the documentation is a bit sparse.  You might want to forget about di annotations until you become a bit more familiar with Symfony.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that by "not shared" you mean that you want to get new instance every time.

You need to set `scope` attribute to `prototype` value as mentioned [here in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html)

I suppose you use [JMSDiExtraBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle) for `@Service` annotation, so let's take a look into the code [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/blob/master/Annotation/Service.php). And we see that `scope` param is handled by this bundle

So in the end I guess it should be something like this:

```
/**
 * @Service("some.service.id", scope="prototype")
 */
```

Comment: Just be aware that for Symfony 3 the scope attribute is depreciated.  A new shared flag has been introduces.  The jms bundle will have to be updated.

Comment: I should have been specific. By not shared i referred to the new shared flag introduced in Symfony 3.

Comment: Do you use JMSDiExtraBundle and Symfony 3? `JMSDiExtraBundle adds more powerful dependency injection features to Symfony2`.

Comment: No i haven't tried that yet. Also scope is deprecated in Symfony 3 so im not sure.

Comment: I meant that you should not even be able to do that, but you didn't denied when I've made that assumption in my answer. What do you use for `@Service` annotation?

Comment: I did not use the `@Service` annotation. I just used the autowire feature. http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-service-auto-wiring

Comment: Well, you didn't clarified that in your question. So how to do you want to do something with annotations if you don't use them? Anyway factory service could solve your problem.